# C# How to load data to messagebox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, messagebox

I have:

```
private void Tab2KsiazkiBTSzczegoly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string KodKsiazki;
        KodKsiazki = DataWyszukajKsiazki.Rows[DataWyszukajKsiazki.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();            
       TSzczegolyDb _szczegoly = new TSzczegolyDb();
       Global.listSzczegoly = _szczegoly.GetSZCZEGOLY(KodKsiazki);


            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in DataWyszukajKsiazki.SelectedCells)
            //{
            //    sb.AppendLine(cell.Value.ToString());
            //}
            //MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        //}
        MessageBox.Show(_szczegoly.ToString());
    }
```

class like that:

```
public class TSzczegolyDb : Core.CoreMSSQL
{
    static string connectionString = TconStrDb.GetConectionString();
    public TSzczegolyDb()
        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public List<TSzczegolyDto> GetSZCZEGOLY(string co)
    {
        List<TSzczegolyDto> list = null;
        list = new List<TSzczegolyDto>();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Tytul, Autorzy, ISBN10, ISBN13, IlStron, Wydawnictwo, Gatunek, Opis FROM dbo.TKsiazki WHERE dbo.TKsiazki.KodKsiazki = '" + co + "'";
        SqlDataReader reader = ExecuteQuery(command);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TSzczegolyDto message = new TSzczegolyDto();
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                message.Tytuł = reader.GetString(0);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                message.Autorzy = reader.GetString(1);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
            {
                message.ISBN10 = reader.GetString(2);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(3))
            {
                message.ISBN13 = reader.GetString(3);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
            {
                message.IlStron = reader.GetInt32(4);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(5))
            {
                message.Wydawnictwo = reader.GetString(5);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(6))
            {
                message.Gatunek = reader.GetString(6);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(7))
            {
                message.Opis = reader.GetString(7);
            }
            list.Add(message);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

and second:

```
public class TSzczegolyDto
{
    private string _tytul;
    public string Tytuł
    {
        get { return _tytul; }
        set { _tytul = value; }
    }

    private string _autorzy;
    public string Autorzy
    {
        get { return _autorzy; }
        set { _autorzy = value; }
    }

    private string _ISBN10;
    public string ISBN10
    {
        get { return _ISBN10; }
        set { _ISBN10 = value; }
    }

    private string _ISBN13;
    public string ISBN13
    {
        get { return _ISBN13; }
        set { _ISBN13 = value; }
    }

    private long _ilstron;
    public long IlStron
    {
        get { return _ilstron; }
        set { _ilstron = value; }
    }

    private string _wydawnictwo;
    public string Wydawnictwo
    {
        get { return _wydawnictwo; }
        set { _wydawnictwo = value; }
    }

    private string _gatunek;
    public string Gatunek
    {
        get { return _gatunek; }
        set { _gatunek = value; }
    }

    private string _opis;
    public string Opis
    {
        get { return _opis; }
        set { _opis = value; }
    }
}
```

I want show `_szczegoly` on MessageBox but when I try to `MessageBox.Show(_szczegoly.ToString());` then is wrong. In `_szczegoly` I have string and long type data.

How to create messagebox with this data?

Comment: I don't see a MessgeBox in your code sample.

Comment: `_szczegoly` is an instance of `TSzczegolyDb`.  Presumably that's a class you wrote.  Did you implement a `.ToString()` method for that class?

Comment: I try:
MessageBox(_szczegoly.ToString());
and
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(DataGridView cell in DataWyszukajKsiazki.SelectedCells)
{
sb.AppendLine(cell.Value.ToString())
}
but this show only what i have ind datagridview, not what i have in query:
"SELECT * FROM dbo.TKsiazki WHERE KodKsiazki = 'something' "

Comment: @DawidWąskiKalinowski Please edit your question with additional details and don't post code in a comment.

Comment: class have:
if(!reader.ISDBNull(i))
{
message.something = reader.GetString(i)
}

Comment: @DawidWąskiKalinowski Only post relevant parts of code. You can take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to show an Object with a MessageBox, you need to override the ToString() method to show propertly:

```
class TSzczegolyDb
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Property1 + this.Property2 /*....*/;
    }
}
```